# How to get an facebook access token for URL

Tags: facebook, authentication, token, facebook-like, facebook-fql

i need to get ids of users who likes particular url, i get an facebook URL object id through FQL

`SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url = 'myurl'`

In return i get for example `500504199505`

Now, when i need to get the list of users who likes that url, i need to use graph api like that:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/500504199505
```

Or FQL like that:

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id='500504199505'
```

But!!!! For that i need an authorisation token.

> So you have to provide an access token with your request associated with an admin account of the page you are trying to get the fans.

But i have just used a social plugin and pasted it to my site, so how can i get that token, how can i be an administrator of particular URL. I am bit confused.

Thanks for help anyone!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out:

- [Facebook Graph API — getting access tokens](http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: So that means that if i want to do that, i have to make some application, then request a token with app ID and after that i will be able to get the list of users who likes that URL? Even if that application has nothing to do with this URL?

Comment: I cannot get this to work. I tried all possible permissions. The example I used is the wikipedia main page: https://graph.facebook.com/6171478891

Comment: There is various useful info posted on this page https://neosmart-stream.de/facebook/how-to-create-a-facebook-access-token/